# How to insert PHP/MYSQL array into a separate JS file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I need to insert an array from a php mysql page into a separate js page. Please assist with where to add the php URL and the format of the php array code for the following result:

```
 template:function(e){
    var t={
        1:{
            title:"I",
            value:"insert"
        },
        2:{
            title:"U",
            class:"update"
        },                          
    };
    return't[e.Status]"
}
```

The php array should be in the following format:
var t={1:{title:"I", value:"insert"},2:{title:"U",class:"update"}

Comment: Can you please show your code and where it fails? Is the "_javascript page_" a seperate `.js` file?

Comment: `t` in this case is an object with other objects in it, an array. You should also show us _all_ the relevant code, like the PHP-part.

Comment: Yes the .js file is a separate file and thus need to use a url to import the data from php. The php file contains the array. var t={1:{title:"I", value:"insert"},2:{title:"U",class:"update"}

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use PHP's `json_encode()` method

#### Example

```
<script>
myVar = <?php json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: How do you use a url php link?

Comment: @Janp what do you mean?

Comment: The js file should pull a php page and therefore one needs a link to a php page. I need to know where to put the url link as well as the format in the js file. The php code and js are not on the same page

Comment: How are you running your js file? i.e. is node running it, or is it being run by a browser, from a HTML file? In either case, you'll probably be after the AJAX method. A js file can't pull data into itself on its own, that's not how JS works.

Comment: I do have a PHP file which include a js file. The js file should build an array from a JSON file. I used AJAX, hereby an example:                                $.ajax({
url: 'json.json',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){
var t=response,                                                                
console.log(response);
}});

Answer (score 0):

You can pass PHP arrays to JavaScript using json_encode PHP function.

```
<?php
$phpArray = array(
    0 => "Mon", 
    1 => "Tue", 
    2 => "Wed", 
    3 => "Thu",
    4 => "Fri", 
    5 => "Sat",
    6 => "Sun",
)
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;

for(var i=0; i<jArray.length; i++){
    alert(jArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: The js file should pull a php page and therefore one needs a link to a php page. I need to know where to put the url link as well as the format in the js file. The php code and js are not on the same page